# Netlify is stuck on "Uploading"

Tags: deployment, publish, netlify

I was building a school application for my class and I had just updated some notes on the website, and thus I wanted to update it by deploying it again. But, I netlify is just stuck on the message "Uploading".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHNfo.png)

[My Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHNfo.png)

Please help me out with this!

Comment: facing the same problem on Netlify while manuel upload

Comment: I solved this problem by uploading reducing the size of the folder. I was foolish and I uploaded an unwanted 'notes' folder into the website folder which contained the 'jpg' or 'png' photos of all the notes. I didn't require this as I was giving out download links and not allowing online viewing. The size of the file exceeded 150MB which caused the delay. I removed it and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Nice to hear that. I solved by updating expo CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by uploading reducing the size of the folder. I was foolish and I uploaded an unwanted 'notes' folder into the website folder which contained the 'jpg' or 'png' photos of all the notes. I didn't require this as I was giving out download links and not allowing online viewing. The size of the file exceeded 150MB which caused the delay. I removed it and that fixed the issue.